# convert ef.utility.cs.ttinclude to classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have converted the classes found in the Visual Studio Entity Framework 5.0 include file (EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude) into a set of standard C# classes. Why I did so is unimportant, suffice it to say that I have good reason for doing so and there isn't another way to accomplish what I wish to accomplish. When attempting to test the classes via a supplied t4 template (the one that generates the standard DbContext for EF), I am receiving the following error:

---

```
Error   1   Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EFUtilities_5_0_DeConstruct, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'EFUtilities_5_0_DeConstruct, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at EFUtilities_5_0_DeConstruct.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(Object textTransformation) in c:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EFExplorer_5\EFUtilities_5_0_DeConstruct\EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6F3E7F749A9B7F1589040546E2B00865752CC91ED5490722E3718CB7A5DDD503FF97964710FBB3EBF135630FF50F8F2A8EA8FA5AA531EC2449158E3D60FD019D.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
```

---

This error occurs in Visual Studio 2012 Premium when after having created a project with a standard Entity Framework data project added and a model built from a database has been generated (the database has a single table with nothing special about it - primary key, couple of test columns) selecting the Build|Transform all T4 menu option (also happens when just selecting the Model1.tt file and selecting "Run Custom Tool"). The Model1.tt (the name is the default assigned) file is the one that fails, the Model1.Context.tt file executes just fine. Both templates have been modified such that they contain the same assembly and import clauses as the EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude file (a cut and paste actually) along with the additional reference to the DeConstruct assembly where the resulting classes are stored. The solution compiles to the standard debug location in "Debug", to a production directory (C:\T4\EF_5_0\Assembiles) for "Release". I have tried setting the Model1.tt file to point to both locations and I get the same error.

The offending line is as noted by the error is:
    DTE dte = (DTE)hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));

envDTE the assembly is added to the references and in the using clause of the class.

The kicker to all this is that I have done this successfully with the EF 4.3.1 EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude file and the corresponding 4.3 DbContext generator files in Visual Studio 2010. Works fine, been having a blast augmenting the basic classes, etc. So...any clues as to why I might see this error just in VS2012 and just with EF 5.0? One thing I haven't tried is bringing EF 5.0 into the VS2010 environment. Kinda didn't want to contaminate a working environment.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

Doesn't matter which version of EnvDTE is selected (the one in the GAC, which shows as "envdte" or the one local to VS2012, which shows as "EnvDTE". Add either one to the project, then, once added, right (off) click the assembly name ("EnvDTE" or "envdte") in the references list, select "Properties" and set the property "Embed Interop Types" to false and rebuild. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Have you moved to EF6 yet?  Curious if you have done the same for the new EF6 include.   About to start on that now.